# Flask form, alert on SelectField onchange

Tags: javascript, flask, onchange, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a SelectField from flask that I include into my html file. I then want to put in a javascript listener that raises an alarm when the value of the SelectField is changed.

When I change the value in the select field the alert is not triggered. Any ideas why?

Here the code:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '897s9ad&sdg/&s'

class ChooseFood(FlaskForm):
    food = SelectField(u'Food', choices=[('1', 'Pizza'), ('2', 'Pasta')])


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ChooseFood()
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

templates/index.html:

```
<form>
    {{form.food}}
</form>

<script>
let food_select = document.get.elementById('food');

food_select.onchange = function(){
        food = food_select.value;
        alert(food);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think this is a typo and should read as follows. `document.getElementById("food")`

Comment: Oh, yes, thats it. Thank you!